# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number after change from php 7.4 to 8.0

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-8, php-8

when I switch my project to php 8.0 I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number (SQL: SELECT locales.locale, directives.id FROM locales LEFT JOIN directives ON directives.user_id = 18 AND directives.locale = locales.locale GROUP BY locales.locale;)
```

here is the code:

```
public function localeStatus($userId, $table)
    {
        $resultRows = DB::select(
            "SELECT locales.locale, $table.id
               FROM locales
               LEFT JOIN $table
                 ON $table.user_id = $userId
                AND $table.locale = locales.locale
              GROUP BY locales.locale;",
            array(1)
        );


        $status = [];
        foreach ($resultRows as $row) {
            $status[$row->locale] = isset($row->id);
        }

        return $status;
    }
```

I think there is a problem parsing the query.
When I run the sql query in phpmyadmin the locales come back and the command works without errors.

Can anyone help me what has changed here in php 8?

Comment: laravel can't differentiate between $table and $user_id and believes bith are varaible to replace

Comment: Thanks nbk. I changed `array(1)` to `['userId' => $userId]` and `$userId` in the query to `:userId` so it works.

Comment: post it as answer add some text and accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks nbk!

I changed `array(1)` to `['userId' => $userId]` and `$userId` in the query to `:userId` so it works.

```
public function localeStatus($userId, $table)
    {
        $resultRows = DB::select(
            "SELECT locales.locale, $table.id
               FROM locales
               LEFT JOIN $table
                 ON $table.user_id = :userId
                AND $table.locale = locales.locale
              GROUP BY locales.locale;",
              ['userId' => $userId]

        );


        $status = [];
        foreach ($resultRows as $row) {
            $status[$row->locale] = isset($row->id);
        }

        return $status;
    }
```